# App to App call not working for ios to android using Sinch SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I'm using Sinch sdk to make an ios and android Calling Application and implementing app-to-app calling feature. I have successfully developed the application for calls done from ios to ios device and android to android device. But when I'm calling from android device to ios device or from ios device to android device, then I can hear the call connecting and dialing tone but nothing is happening at other platform end, call is not reaching there.

When i'm checking the log i'm getting status as "NO ANSWER" , but on other platform there is no call received. Please let me know what is the solution for this issue.

Code details:

```
if (mobile != nil) && self.client.isStarted() {

    client.call().delegate = self

    fullname = "\(dataArray[indexpathRow]["firstName"] as! String) \(dataArray[indexpathRow]["middleName"] as! String) \(dataArray[indexpathRow]["lastName"] as! String)"


    let header: [String: String] = ["callerCallId": (logInDataModelObject?.user_id)!, "callerType": "1", "recieverCallId": "\(dataArray[indexpathRow]["id"] as! String)", "recieverType": "1", "CallerName": fullname!, "CallerPhoto": dataArray[indexpathRow]["photo"] as! String]

    weak var call: SINCall? = client.call().callUser(withId: mobile, headers: header)

    let controller1: CallViewController = CallViewController(nibName: "CallViewController", bundle: nil)

    viewCallingAppear = true

    controller1.title = "Call"
    controller1.call = call
    controller1.callingPersonName = fullname
    controller1.userImage = dataArray[indexpathRow]["photo"] as? String

    self.navigationController?.present(controller1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

// MARK: - SINCallClientDelegate
func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {

    if let rootViewController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        //do sth with root view controller
        print(rootViewController)

        let controller1: CallViewController = CallViewController(nibName: "CallViewController", bundle: nil)
        controller1.call = call

        let header = call.headers
        controller1.callingPersonName = header!["CallerName"] as! String
        controller1.userImage = header!["CallerPhoto"] as! String
        rootViewController.present(controller1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: check the session id and session and Stream..are you sending the stream from both end\....Please the related code here..

Comment: @MAhipalSingh thanks for reply, edited my query with code

Comment: Please send a ticket to Snich support team